# Where can I get Xceed CheckComboBox (Community edition) Style and Templates

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, xceed

Is it possible to extract all Style and Templates for **Xceed CheckComboBox** ? Generally for built in wpf components(that come with WPF), I extract all styles from Visual Studio by right clicking a wpf control in designer, and then "**Extract Template**" or "**Extract Additional Templates**". But somehow I am not able to get full set of styles for the Xceed **CheckComboBox**. How do I get the styles to make changes, or where can I find that documentation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the styles using the Expression Blend. 
refer the image
[image]

Comment: Actually I don't have blend installed, but that's possible in Visual Studio too. Is it possible to get addition templates specifically the one's that target Item in Visual Studio. Because I don't get options to edit those. I can certainly extract the Main Template with VS, but not additional templates.

Comment: what do you mean by additional templates buddy

Comment: ItemContainerStyle template, like the one that I get when I target ComboBoxItem. But your response is correct. So I will mark it as one. Just to add, this is also possible in VS 2013. I was hoping there is some documentation site from xceed